# Haskell: Treating Bool as Int

Tags: haskell

How would one implement a function that started with an int, and subtracted 1 from it for every time (going through a finite number of possibilities) one of several (for example, 5) boolean values returned 1.

How this would ideally look look is:

```
function list1 list2 = num
  where
      num = 4
          - (condition from var1 = true)
          - (condition from var2 = true)
          - (so on, so forth as long as needed)
```

I have tried implementing these lines similarly to:

```
      num = startVal
          - (list1conditional == desiredVal)
          - (etc)
```

But this is returning type errors.

Comment: You can use `fromEnum`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Bool` is an instance of `Enum`: you can enumerate the two values of a `Bool`: `False`, and then `True`.

As a result, it implements the [**`fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum), a function that maps a value of an `Enum` type to an `Int`: for a `Bool`, it maps `False` to `0`, and `True` to `1`.

So we can use this like:

```
result = 5 - fromEnum cond1 - fromEnum cond2
```

Or for example with a list of conditions:

```
result = 5 - sum (map fromEnum [cond1, cond2, cond3])
```

where `cond1` and `cond2`, etc. are expressions of type `Bool`.

Comment: Can you do this the other way around?

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer: what should be the result for values not equal to `0`/`1`?

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer: you can make use of `toEnum 0 :: Bool` to convert `0` to `False` and `1` to `True`. But this will raise an error for values outside the `0`/`1` range.

Comment: I didn’t really care for values different from 0/1. It was for homework that I needed to define some different implementations of the not function. I based myself on the previous answer to find the fancy not = even.fromEnum. If one does not care about ‘fanciness’, you can just use x/=0.

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer: well you can use `toEnum`, but unless some signature of the caller forces it to be a `Bool`, you thus will have to specify a type hint, so `toEnum 0 :: Bool`, `toEnum 1 :: Bool` will return `False` and `True` respectively.